# Give 777 permission to dynamically created file in php

Tags: php, apache, save

Hi i have a script which **dynamically** created a file on my local directory 
Please tell me how can i give 777 permission to that file right now it is unaccessible in the browser

```
<?php
//Get the file
$content = 'http://xxx.xxx.com.mx/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/r/bridal-shoes1.jpg ';
$content1 = explode('/', $content);
$end = end($content1);
echo $end;
//print_r($content1[12]);
//Store in the filesystem.
$my_file = $end;
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates file
$path = '/var/www/'.$end;

copy($content, $path);

 ?>
```

Comment: i simply drop this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php here. Just use that on your file

Comment: **Big fat bold warning**: 0777 permissions give *anyone* on that machine with the path to the file permission to open it, modify it, or *execute the contents*.  0777 is a *gigantic* security risk and you should do whatever you can to avoid needing it.  You **do not** need 0777 permissions just to have the file read by a browser.  0644 should do the job just fine.

Comment: @Charles Let's suppose I am a developer and I need to write debug logging into a file. I consider making it 777. Is it still a risk even in such circumstances?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use the function chmod
[chmod](https://www.php.net/function.chmod)

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
chmod($file, 0777);
```

Comment: what if we don't have write permission in the directory, do `chmod` still work?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to set file permissions.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
private function writeFileContent($file, $content){
   $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
   fwrite($fp, $content);
   fclose($fp);
   chmod($file, 0777);  //changed to add the zero
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Give permission in to dynamically created file**

```
                  $upPath = yourpath;
                    if(!file_exists($upPath)) 
                    {
                        $oldmask = umask(0);
                        mkdir($upPath, 0777, true);
                        umask($oldmask);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chmod()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_chmod.asp) to do this.

e.g. `chmod($my_file, 0777);`

Answer (score 0):

set `default permission` to u r directory (i.e `rwx`) using `setfacl command`

```
ex: setfacl -d -m o::rwx your/directory/path
```

then any thing u create in that directory it takes `rwx` permission.

Answer (score 0):

we can **even** ignore  ****$handle**** it will still **create** the **file** and **copy** the content to the  **$path**

```
 <?php
    //Get the file
    $content = 'http://dev.aviesta.com.mx/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/r/bridal-shoes1.jpg ';
    $content1 = explode('/', $content);
    $end = end($content1);
    echo $end;
    //print_r($content1[12]);
    //Store in the filesystem.
    $my_file = $end;
    $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates file
    $path = '/var/www/'.$end;

    copy($content, $path);

     ?>
```